# Subtract a circle on a rectangle - OpenGL

Tags: c++, bullet-physics, glm, glfw, glew

I am writing a game using GLFW, GLEW, GLM and Bullet3 in C++. Its a Maze with holes. I am doing the floor with rectangles (wich is 2 GL_TRIANGLES).

I want to make some woles (circles), to the ball fall out of the board. What the best way to do that? How can I subtract a circle to the floor? And add the shape to the Bullet3?

Thanks